# apex:outputfield on hover display value using tooltip

Tags: css, datatable, mousehover

I have a datatable with css overflow : hidden. Now for big digit numbers, I want for a particular column, 15th here, enable on hover show value using tooltip. The hover part is working fine and showing the value but the outputfield itself is not showing any value.

Here is the style used:

```
/*BG color is a must for IE6*/
td:nth-child(15):hover {
    background: #e1f1f7; 
}
td:nth-child(15).tooltip span {
    display:none; 
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
td:nth-child(15).tooltip:hover span {
    display:inline; 
    position:absolute; 
    border:1px solid #cccccc; 
    background:white; 
    color:#6c6c6c;
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:column style="border: 1px solid #a1b4bf" styleClass="tooltip"><span>kk</span>
    <apex:outputField value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_Total__c}" id="Total" style="background-color:transparent" >

    </apex:outputfield>  
    <apex:facet name="header">
        {!$ObjectType.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c.Fields.Abv_Core_KAM_Total__c.Label}
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

what are the other alternatives for doing this ? thanks in advance !